# Can CRC8 be calculated by the receiving ECU if it's not subscribed to all the signals in a frame? Thank you

Tags: checksum, autosar, crc8

There's 8 bytes in a frame, first byte is the Checksum. The transmitting node will calculate a checksum using the CRC8 formula, based on all 8 bytes. Will the receiving node be able to calculate the same exact checksum if it is not subscribed to all the signals in that frame? I can't find anything in SAE J1850. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how SAE J1850 is related to the CRC8 of received PDUs, e.g. from CAN.

Beyond that, the CRC for E2E protection is calculated based on the hex data in the PDU, not on the decoded signals.

Because of that, this is no problem.

I had this in three projects, all using E2E protection wrapper, and for the transformer, it is the same, as the frame encoding does not change with that.

Comment: I think he's refering to `E2E Profile 1 uses CRC-8-SAE J1850`, while `E2E Profile 2 shall use the Crc_CalculateCRC8H2F`. In the end, it should be eaiser with the E2EXf, since you do not need to reassemble the PDU in the SWC in order to check the CRC. This is done now in the E2EXf, before it's passed to the ComXf transformers as array of bytes.